# Make v-validate field dynamic

Tags: html

I have a user input text box on my form. The visibility is based on myboolean which is set in the js file. I would also like v-validate:field_title to be dependent on myboolean. Currently if v-validate:field_title="['required']" there must be text in the field in order to submit the form.

```
 `<div class="form-group" v-show="myboolean == 'true'">
      <label for="field_title">Field Title: </label>
      <input id="field_title"
      class="form-control field_title_typeahead title"
      name="field_title" type="text"
      placeholder="Select Field"
      autocomplete="off" value=""
      v-validate:field_title="['required']">
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the class with a v-if tag seemed to do the trick.

```
<div v-if="myboolean == 'true'">
      <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field_title">Field Title: </label>
              <input id="field_title"
              class="form-control field_title_typeahead title"
              name="field_title" type="text"
              placeholder="Select Field"
              autocomplete="off" value=""
              v-validate:field_title="['required']">
      </div>
</div
```